# Handling non constant global configuration in a multithreaded c++ server application

Tags: c++, multithreading, configuration, thread-safety, global-variables

I'm in the process of designing a multithreaded c++ server application, that services clients in their own thread, and also has various other worker threads that carry out other tasks.

All of these threads will rely on a single text config file that needs to be able to be rehashed without exiting and restarting the process.

I'm currently looking at having each client and worker thread have it's own copy of the config object, and then having this update at each rehash.

One thing I've found with this is that passing the config around to all the other utility functions that I'd prefer and don't think should be a a part of one the the above mentioned classes can seem to get incredibly tedious.

Having a global config would be so much easier, except for the painful need for a lot of synchronisation.

Open to any ideas on how to address having a non constant global config in a thread application!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I like to do this is to always carry the config as a shared_ptr to a const object. Whenever you need the config (keeping consistency in mind; it's often better to handle an entire request with the same config even though the config is technically outdated by the end of the request-handling code), you get a shared_ptr to it. Background worker tasks can reset the value of their shared_ptr at convenient points in the work cycle, trying to avoid holding on to a config too long (since it may become outdated).

If there is only one task which can change the config, this works nicely; it constructs a completely new config object, and then resets its shared_ptr, [edit]which it keeps protected with a lock, see below[/edit]. As soon as no other task is using the old config object, the old one disappears.

One detail: you can't pass around pointers to parts of the config object unless you are sure you're going to hold on to the shared_ptr to that config object as long as the pointers will last. This can be irritating if the config includes, for example, a map of names to sub-configurations.

While there is some overhead to shared pointers, it's probably less than keeping entire copies of the config in synch (unless, of course, the config is tiny, and if it were we probably wouldn't be having this conversation). Config changes are relatively rare in most apps, so it is very unlikely that you'll have more than two config objects at any given time. You can usually arrange to keep shared_ptr creation to one per request, so the shared_ptr synchronization is trivial.

YMMV, but I've found that it works out pretty well.

[Edit] As pointed out by a couple of commenters, I should have been explicit about the locking requirements. The config updater keeps a master shared_ptr which is protected with a read-write lock. It needs to hold a write lock while it is updating the pointer. It also exports an interface which returns a shared_ptr to the current configuration; that interface copies the shared_ptr while holding a read lock. Since configuration changes are rare and the shared_ptr is tiny, there is very little lock contention.[1]

Aside from the configuration task itself, no-one else should need to have to worry about locks, since the other shared_ptr's should not be shared by multiple tasks: every task should just get its own.

[1] While I was writing this, I realized that the way I've been doing this, which involved calling .reset on the master shared_ptr, actually might hold the write lock for too long if the configuration's destructor is slow (possible if the configuration contains a huge number of std::string's, for example). It might be better to expand the implementation of reset (which is just a swap with a temporary NULL shared_ptr), putting the swap inside of the lock guard and letting the destructor (of the temporary) run unlocked. However, given how rare config changes are (at least in any server I've been associated with), I doubt whether it makes any appreciable difference.

Comment: Yep, this is a good approach, no need for any locking. I've been using a similar one.

Comment: Yup - just swap out the shared_ptr, entire config object changes atomically from one valid version to the next - job done.  Anything that wants to change the config can do it by messaging the one thread that manages the config.  On GUI apps, I usually use the GUI thread for that - makes it easier/safer to view/edit the config manually.

Comment: shared_ptr.reset is atomic?! Is this something new in c++11 or something I've plain missed?

Comment: @Troy - good point. The shared_ptr class itself is not, which is why you need a pointer to it.  You do use new() for most of your objects in your multithreaded code, surely?  <g>

Comment: ..and the answer to your next qustion is - I don't,  I just let it leak.  You could, I guess, make the shared_ptr part of the config struct/object itself and the last decrementer of the ref would then cause the shared_ptr to delete itself via the config destructor.  Never been brave enough to try that..

Comment: @Troy, yes, quite right. That was quite sloppy; I added a note making the lock requirement explicit.

Comment: @rici In C++ 20 we may use `std::atomic<std::shard_ptr<foo>>`; [Ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) or atomic_store and atomic_load on `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this part:

*One thing I've found with this is that passing the config around to all the other utility functions that I'd prefer and don't think should be a a part of one the the above mentioned classes can seem to get incredibly tedious.*

Anyway, look up on **thread-local storage**. You could make a singleton config object that is thread-local.

Comment: From your suggestion I think you understood that part fine. Thread-local-storage would solve it perfectly. Any idea if boost::thread_specific_ptr incurs much of a performance penalty? From what I've read in the past there seems to be some that frown on using thread_local stoage as a design problem.

Comment: Im curious about the singleton: If its only used in one thread, then why use a singleton? Couldnt you just use a simple object instantiated in that particular thread and store it in thread-local storage?

Comment: @Troy I don't think there's any performance penalty (unless it's something Boost itself does). Accessing a thread-local object is just like accessing normal object. The only magic happens when a new thread is created. As for the second thing, I don't see how thread-local storage relates to design.

Comment: @Brady The singleton is simply a matter of design. A singleton is like a global variable except it's considered good design, whereas global variables are considered bad design :)

Comment: Yes, I know what a singleton is. Im just used to using it in a different context. I would think that the config could be a part of the object used in each thread.

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled with one single config object that is shared by all threads. This config class should have 2 parts:

1. Reading and parsing the config file
2. Access to the config data by all threads

Reading and parsing of the config file should be handled from only one thread, preferably the main thread. This part will be isolated from the rest of the threads. When an update has been made, then the config data that the rest of the threads access can be updated via a pthread_rwlock using a write lock. When the threads access the config data, they should use a read lock.

In case you're not familiar with a rw (read/write) lock, there can be multiple simultaneous read locks that dont block unless a write lock is being performed. There can only be one write lock at a time. So, in this context, all of the threads can simultaneously read the config data without any locking contention. There will only be locking while reading when the config data is updated by the main thread after a rehash.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, having a mutable global object in a multi-threaded application will require synchronization if threads are accessing and mutating the object. You can keep the global config, with some caveats, and still not worry about synchronization if you add an extra layer when accessing the config. Every thread can have a pointer to the global config and if every thread is simply reading from the config then this is fine. However, when you need to change the config, set a flag for the member you are accessing and store that someplace local to the thread. Every time you access the config you must check this flag and then return the appropriate data. This has a pretty big advantage in the design of the code as well as it forces you to flesh out an interface to the config, so all the code that consumes the config will never have to change if you decide in the future to change the way accessing a config is done.

Answer (score 0):

The other good solution, in addition to those already posted, is a DB table.  A DB can provide better control of transactions with the config and so provide better integrity of the data.  It could provide protection from those cases where an inappropriate change is made to existing config because the change is based on older, out-of-date config.

Yes, it's slower and probably overkill for OP use, (especially if no DB already!), but should be mentioned for completeness.